# Storing external access/refresh tokens

Tags: laravel, encryption, oauth, access-token, refresh-token

I've created a Laravel application which requests my users access to an external application using oAuth (authorization code). All good, I'm able to connect the external application to my users' accounts. However, the external API gives me an access and refresh token. The access token obviously expires, the refresh token doesn't.

Once the user has granted me access, I need to store these tokens somewhere. Especially the refresh token. Once the access token expires, I need to refresh the access token. My "problem" is, I'm not quite sure where to store these tokens. I have thought of a few options:

- Storing encrypted tokens in the database, linked to the user
- Store them in cache
- Store them in Redis database
- ...

There are many options, but I'm looking for the safest one. Storing the encrypted tokens in the database isn't my favorite choice, but the most persistent one. Cache can be cleared, deliberately or not. When the cache is cleared, I need the user to grant me access to their account again.

What's the best way of storing these credentials?

Comment: You may not have to store the tokens at all (other than in the session, that is). Most providers remember the user's consent, so authorization flows following the first one are non-interactive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Security

> What's the best way of storing these credentials?
> There are many options, but I'm looking for the safest one.

No matter where you store it, always do it in an encrypted format. This way even if leaked they cannot be reused, unless the encryption key is also leaked.

### Refresh Token Persistence

> Storing the encrypted tokens in the database isn't my favorite choice, but the most persistent one.

You can do it with sessions, JWT tokens or directly into a database. Let's see the options...

#### Laravel Sessions

If you are using user sessions in your Laravel application you can store it encrypted in the session for each user.

[Laravel Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session)

> Since HTTP driven applications are stateless, sessions provide a way to store information about the user across multiple requests. Laravel ships with a variety of session backends that are accessed through an expressive, unified API. Support for popular backends such as Memcached, Redis, and databases is included out of the box.

Laravel also supports to store the session in encrypted cookies.

#### JWT Tokens

If you are using JWT tokens then your are probably using a JWS token, then if so store it encrypted in a JWS claim or even better, use JWE tokens.

The claim in a JWT token is a key/value pair in the payload of the JWT token. The JWT Token is composed by `header.payload.signature`. Payload example:

```json
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

[JWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Signature)

> A JSON Web Signature (abbreviated JWS) is an IETF-proposed standard (RFC 7515) for signing arbitrary data.[1] This is used as the basis for a variety of web-based technologies including JSON Web Token.

[JWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Encryption)

> JSON Web Encryption (JWE) is an IETF standard providing a standardised syntax for the exchange of encrypted data, based on JSON and Base64.[1] It is defined by RFC7516. Along with JSON Web Signature (JWS), it is one of the two possible formats of a JWT (JSON Web Token). JWE forms part of the JavaScript Object Signing and Encryption (JOSE) suite of protocols.

You can learn more about JWT at https://jwt.io/introduction.

#### Databases

Use the database more convenient for you, aka the one already available in your application. Don't introduce Redis just to store the refresh token, but if you already have Redis in use, then it can be an alternative, but I would just store it encrypted in the database you already store the user info. After all refreshing a token is not an operation you do in every request, therefore performance may not be so critical here.

Comment: Nitpick: JWS doesn't encrypt data, so technically the refresh_token is not secured there but only validated.

Comment: I said  to store the refresh token encrypted in a JWS claim, therefore even if the attacker extract it from a JWS it will be useless. I also recommend to use instead a JWE token that is encrypted. Maybe I need to make the message more clear?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by a claim. The original RFC doesn't use that terminology.

Comment: The [RFC 7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519) states the claims in its abstract, but you may want to read instead [this introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/). Basically a claim is each key/value pair in the payload of the JWT token, and the payload is the middle part of the three components of the JWT token, aka `header.payload.signature`.

Comment: Ok, so the claims are not encrypted when using only JWS without JWE.

Answer (score 1):

Memory and encrypted db are your best bet. Memory would not be enough as you will lose it in case of a memory flush of any kind. So you are left with encrypted DB